# Is this how you calculate the reservation price?

Tags: probability, searching

I was wondering if you could help me make sure I have things correct. Weitzman (1979) (Optimal search for the best alternative) considers a decision maker that is facing n boxes, each box has potential reward $x_i $with probability distribution $f(x_i)$ (iid). It costs $c_i$ to open the box and learn its contents. There is a discount factor $\beta_i$ for each box. The paper shows that each box has a reservation price $z_i$ that satisfies:

\begin{equation}
c_i = \beta_i \int_{z_i}^\infty (x_i-z_j)\textrm{d}f(x_i)-(1-\beta_i)z_i
\end{equation}

Then, the paper gives a specific example where $\beta_i=1$, each box has reward $R_i$ with probability $p_i$ and reward of 0 with probability $1-p_i$. It is given that in this case:
\begin{equation}
z_i=(p_i*R_i-c_i)/p_i 
\end{equation}

Now, I'm trying to find out what the $z_i$ would be if $0<\beta_i<1.$ I believe that it is:
\begin{equation}
z_i=(\beta_i*p_i*R_i-c_i)/(\beta_i*p_i+(1-\beta_i))
\end{equation}

The reason I believe this is the solution is due to the following steps i took:
\begin{equation}
\int_{z_i}^\infty (x_i-z_j)\textrm{d}f(x_i)=p_i*(R_i-z_i)
\end{equation}
(I got this from the solution the paper provided for the case where $\beta_i=1$.)

Then, we have 
\begin{equation}
c_i = \beta_i*p_i*(R_i-z_i)-(1-\beta_i)z_i
\end{equation}

And,
\begin{equation}
c_i = \beta_i*p_i*R_i-\beta_i*p_i*z_i-(1-\beta_i)z_i
\end{equation}

Thus, 
\begin{equation}
c_i = \beta_i*p_i*R_i-z_i*[\beta_i*p_i+(1-\beta_i)]
\end{equation}

Giving us,
\begin{equation}
z_i=(\beta_i*p_i*R_i-c_i)/(\beta_i*p_i+(1-\beta_i))
\end{equation}

However, I had previously calculated it as 
\begin{equation}
z_i=(\beta_i*p_i*R_i-c_i)/(\beta_i*p_i)
\end{equation}
(I don't know how I had calculated this) and now I am doubting myself as to which one is the correct solution. Can you help me here?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. You literally copied the question form the screenshot, without embedding the formulas in a math environment (mathjax). Besides, you have not shown any work, most communitymembers do not like to answer such question in which the author did not put too much effort into them. Anyway, to help you, I've edited your question

Comment: Thank you for editing my question. My apologies for the format, the reason I included the screenshot was because the math looks "tidier" there, since I don't know how to use Mathjax. Is there a tutorial on how to use it? Of does the comment area accept Latex code to convert to math? I'm a bit lost on how to use this forum most efficiently. Thank you.

Comment: That's alright :). Sure! It's similiar to using latex. Look for basic latex tutorials and use dollar signs to format your questions. Things such as z_i turn into $z_i$ etcetera.

Comment: Thank you very much, i was able to figure it out. i edited the text to add some steps I used and removed the screenshot, thanks again.

Comment: For reference, here is a mathjax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference